# Paperclip on S3 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to use Paperclip with Amazon S3 on my Rails 4.2.3 app.

Everything works fine if I use Paperclip storing data locally on my machine.
Problems are when I try to use Paperclip storing files on S3.

For example, simply trying to create a new User instance fires an error:

```
u = User.new
u.name = "Mark"
u.save
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/paperclip-4.3.6/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:84:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/paperclip-4.3.6/lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:47:in `new'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/paperclip-4.3.6/lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:47:in `block in define_instance_getter'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activemodel-4.2.6/lib/active_model/validator.rb:149:in `block in validate'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activemodel-4.2.6/lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `each'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activemodel-4.2.6/lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `validate'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `public_send'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `block in make_lambda'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `call'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `block in simple'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
... 22 levels...
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Augusto/Sites/ccu_test/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Augusto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem "pg"
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'
gem "paperclip", '~> 4.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
```

I've installed ImageMagik and added to my development.rb

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

My model:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {:micro => "32x32#", :thumb => "50x50#", :big_thumb => "80x80#", :small => "220x220>", :featured => "220x220#", :medium => "600x600>"}#, :default_url => 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/ccu-static/file.small.png'
end
```

config > initializers > paperclip_defaults.rb

```
module Paperclip
  class Attachment
    def self.default_options
      @default_options ||= {
        :storage           => :s3,
        :url               => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
        :path              => "/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
        :styles            => {},
        :processors        => [:thumbnail],
        :convert_options   => {},
        :default_url       => "/images/missing.:style.gif", #"http://s3.amazonaws.com/ccu-static/missing.:style.png", 
        :default_style     => :original,
        :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
        :whiny             => Paperclip.options[:whiny] || Paperclip.options[:whiny_thumbnails]
      }
    end
  end
end
```

config > initializers > aws.rb

```
Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-west-2',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('...', '...')
})
```

config > S3.yml

```
production:
  bucket: ...
  access_key_id: ...
  secret_access_key: ...
development:
  bucket: ...
  access_key_id: ...
  secret_access_key: ...
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name",           limit: 255
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type",        limit: 255
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  end
```